# What's the best architecture to mix C code and a ASP Classic website

Tags: javascript, c, asp-classic

I have to create a real-time display. On this display I have to get the numbers from an existing business logic component (written in C) and display these Live on a classic ASP-page (legacy app).

How can I best structure this solution to reuse the existing c code without refactoring the legacy asp classic website?

Comment: I have edited to make it more about software engineering rather than a direct tech question. But I think the close votes are a bit overkill. Mixing various existing components to create a solution is a high level architecture question. even if a specific coding technique might be used to resolve it

Comment: Ok, but I still don't really get it what to do next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used to develop asp classic by putting the business logic in com+ components which can then be referenced and used by light weight vb script in the asp page.

I used vb6, but I believe you can make com+ dll in any language

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13601/COM-in-plain-C

Overall I would recommend this approach in any classic asp project, as it allows you to separate the business logic from the view and program in a modern way.

Com+ is legacy technology now, but then so is classic asp. Here are some guides

http://www.chestysoft.com/component-services.asp

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524620(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Hello Ewan, thanks for the information. Is com+ a tool, that I have to download it?

Comment: com+ is a way if packaging dlls so they can be exposed to other windows processes. you register your com+ component and then you can instanciate it in your asp page and call the functionality in vb script

Comment: ok, I will read the information which you gave me. For Me these are very new, I hope I will understand these :) Thank you!

Comment: remember to upvote and select answer!!

Comment: how can I upvote? I clicked usefil button, but nothing hanppens

Comment: look like some people are trying to close your question. ill edit it to make it more on topic

Comment: @MiMeng you'll earn the "vote up" privilege at 15 reputation score. See /help/privileges for all the details.